# SharePoint Online Plan 1 and jQuery

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, jquery, master-page, scriptlink

I'm working on a SharePoint Online Plan 1 Site Collection in preparation for our Office 365 deployment and I'm getting a lot of requests for small UI changes and tweaks (make certain Library Columns bold, change the way the Announcements  Web Part looks, etc.)

Ultimately it sounds like having jQuery available will help me address some of these requests. I'm not a Javascript whiz but I feel comfortable enough working with it (and who doesn't love a little jQuery now and then?)

Long story short I'm not finding any clear, easy way to make jQuery **available via my Master Page** (is that a sensible strategy? Using SharePoint ScriptLink?)

I've got SharePoint Designer all set up and have been messing around with it for a while but not having any luck getting this figured out from scouring the Internet.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to add jquery to your  masterpage?

Comment: I... I think so? I'm looking to make jQuery available on all of the pages in the site.
I have jQuery in
/_catalogs/masterpage/jQuery-1.11.3.min.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It worked! Thank you for your help @Keerthi!
For future confused individuals like myself this is what worked:

With the jQuery library in the Site Assets library I created a new Script Editor web part with the following snippet:

```
<script src="/SiteAssets/jQuery.1.11.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

**alternatively you can replace the line above with this line to get jQuery via CDN**
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script>
YOUR JQUERY HERE
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a javascript file using the content web part.

*Edit page -> Add web part -> Media and content -> Content editor -> Add*

*Edit the source of the web part and add the following code into it:*

```
​<script src="/sites/subsite/list/SiteAssets/file.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Add the js file under Site Assets using SharePoint Designer.

Comment: Shouldn't I be using the Script Editor web part?

Comment: In my case, I had some issues using it. You can also try with that

Comment: Do I need both of the script lines?

I just tried this:   
`​<script src="/SiteAssets/jQuery-1.11.3.min.js" type="text/javascript">
blahblah my jQuery code
</script>`
   ... which didn't work

Comment: You are completely wrong. One script tag is used to include the Jquery library and the other is your actual Javascript file.